# Showing a $k$-algebra isomorphism

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a finite dimensional $k$-algebra. I want to show that $A\otimes_{k}M_n(k)\cong M_n(A)$ for any positive integr $n$. Can you show how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have \begin{align*}\phi:A\times\operatorname{Mat}_n(K)&\to\operatorname{Mat}_n(A)\\ (a,M)&\mapsto aM\end{align*} a well-defined  bilinear homomorphism. By definition of the tensor product this means there is a unique linear map  $\varphi$, such that

[image]

commutes.

This map is given by
\begin{align*}\varphi:A\otimes_K\operatorname{Mat}_n(K)&\to\operatorname{Mat}_n(A)\\ a\otimes M&\mapsto aM.\end{align*}  This is a homomorphism. Note that   ${A\otimes_K\operatorname{Mat}_n(K)}$ and $\operatorname{Mat}_n(A)$ have the same dimension. To show that  $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, it  suffices to show that  $\varphi$ is surjective.

Now take the matrix  $E_{ij}$ (the matrix with all zeroes, exept for the entry $(i,j)$). A random  matrix $N=(n_{ij})\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(A)$ is now the image of $\sum\limits_{ij}(n_{ij}, E_{ij})$ under $\varphi$. This makes   $\phi$ and thus also $\varphi$ surjective. Since this implies $\varphi$ is an  isomorphism, we're done.

Comment: Appologies for the image, however I was not able to format the diagram using MathJaX. I'll edit as soon as I know how.

Comment: You are assuming A as a right k-vector space.And $Mat_n(k)$ is same as $M_n(k)$ right?

Comment: @2015 Yes absolutely. I should have asked for clarification, but I assumed $k$ is a field, and that algebras are associative Also $\operatorname{Mat_n}(k)$ is the algebra of matrices with entries in $k$ and the dimension is the dimension seen as a vectorspace.

Comment: I don't think you don't need to assume that A is a finite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: @2015 Is this all as you intended, or have I assumed to much?

Comment: @gebruiker That is what I need. Thank you very much.@Bubbles how do you show this isomorphism if A is not finite dimensional vector space as the dimension argument does not work.

Comment: @2015 Simply note that the ranks of the respective free A-modules are the same. Hence a surjection must be an isomorphism. This is a standard fact that follows from nakayama's lemma.